# Fail to load response data jquery.easy-autocomplete.min.js:10 WARNING:

Tags: javascript, jquery, easyautocomplete

I am using the easyautocomplete, http://easyautocomplete.com/, to populate a list as the user types in a search field. The code is as follows:

```
var options = {
  url: function(phrase) {
      if (phrase !== "") {
          return "http://<url>/todo?query=" + phrase + "&format=json";
      } else {
          return "http://<url>/todo?query=empty&format=json";
      }
  },

  getValue: "results",

  ajaxSettings: {
      dataType: "jsonp"
  },

  requestDelay: 300,

  theme: "round"
  };

  $("#product-list").easyAutocomplete(options);
```

I am getting a response from my API that looks like:

```
{
"results": [
    "list_item_1",
    "list_item_2",
    "list_item_3",
    ...
    "list_item_50"
    ]
}
```

I have a feeling I'm not formatting the response properly, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

A look through the guide it looks like `getValue` would be if you had an array of objects and wanted to pull a particular key from each one. From the [list location section](http://easyautocomplete.com/guide#sec-list-location) it looks like you are looking for `listLocation` to specify the object key that has the array of things to autocomplete. So changing `getValue` to `listLocation` should give you the results you are looking for

Comment: Thanks.  I had to change the dataType from **jsonp** to **json** and change the **getValue** to **listLocation**.  Unfortunately, when I change the dataType to jsonp I lose CORS.